# Java Overloading method and interface

Tags: java

I am trying to learn Java
I tried to solve this problem with overloading but when I try to do, too many methods occur, how can I solve it in a short way?

I have ComplexN>RealN>RationalN>IntegerN>NaturalN classes and I extended this classes each other.
Then I make an interface class named Arithmetic for making arithmetic operation with these classes.

```
public interface Arithmetic {


    static ComplexN add(ComplexN c1,ComplexN c2) {
ComplexN complex=newComplexN(c1.getRealPart()+c2.getRealPart(),c1.getImaginaryPart()+c2.getImaginaryPart());  
    return complex;

    }


    static ComplexN add(ComplexN c1 ,RealN r1) {
        ComplexN complex = new ComplexN(c1.getRealPart()+ r1.getRealPart(),c1.getImaginaryPart());
        return  complex;
    }
```

I don't want overloading methods to go on like this, because there are dozens of methods
I want all of them to be processed with each other. How can I solve this in the shortest way

Comment: Why do you not want overloading methods if that makes the most semantic sense?

Comment: If all of these classes inherit from each other, you could take advantage of that. Take the most basic class and put it as both the parameters, then anything that inherits from that type will be able to be passed in. Since you have different logic for different types, you would probably have to check which type each parameter is within the method (which won't be too different than having different overloads), but it can all be in one method.

Comment: What _exactly_ is the extension relationship between these types?  Does RealN extend ComplexN, or the other way around, or neither?  If RealN extends ComplexN, then you wouldn't need the second method.

Comment: @whiplash because I have 4 Arithmetic operation and for one operation I need to overload at least 15 methods.I think there should be a shorter way.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Real extends Complex > Rational extends Real and it goes like this. What should I do

Answer (score 0):

Since you have said that e.g. `RealN extends ComplexN`, you don't need do have separate `(Complex, Real)` methods, for example.  All you need is

```
    static ComplexN add(ComplexN c1,ComplexN c2) { ... }
    static RealN add(RealN r1, RealN r2) { ... }
    static RationalN add(RationalN r1, RationalN r2) { ... }
    static IntegerN add(IntegerN i1, IntegerN i2) { ... }
    static NaturalN add(NaturalN i1, NaturalN n2) { ... }
```

You don't need any more methods than that.  If you call `add` with a `ComplexN` and a `RealN` value, then this will just treat the `RealN` value as its supertype `ComplexN`, which is the correct behavior.